# Making fgets issue longer read() calls on linux

Tags: c, linux, stdio

I'm reading quite large lines(up to 128K) of text using `fgets`. I'm seeing excessive context switching on the server, using `strace` I see the following:

```
read(3, "9005 10218 00840023102015 201008"..., 4096) = 4096
```

i.e. `fgets` reads chunks of 4096 bytes at a time. Is there any way to control how big chunks `fgets` uses to when calling `read()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setvbuf` would be the obvious place to start.

Comment: I'd like e.g. a *large* buffer though, but issuing reads in somewhat smaller chunks. with setvbuf I'd have to set a max size of the buffer and the reads are issued in the size of buffer (e.g. a buffer of 128k, sissues reads in 128k chunks, which actually turns out to perform worse than doing reads of 8192 bytes, in my case)

Answer (score 2):

The function `fgets()` is part of the stdio package, and as such it must buffer (or not) the input stream in a way that is consistent with also using `fgetc()`, `fscanf()`, `fread()` and so forth. That means that the buffer itself (if the stream is buffered) is the property of the `FILE` object.

Whether there is a buffer or not, and if buffered, how large the buffer is, can be suggested to the library by calling `setvbuf()`.

The library implementation has a fair amount of latitude to ignore hints and do what it thinks best, but buffers that are "reasonable" powers of two in size will usually be accepted. You've noticed that the default was 4096, which is clearly smaller than optimal.

The stream is buffered by default if it is opened on an actual file. Its buffering on a pipe, FIFO, TTY or anything else potentially has different defaults.