# Using setvbuf() with STDIN stream

Tags: c, stream, stdin

I’m writing a small C program that must accept an input stream larger than 4096 bytes.

I did find a post that recommended using **setvbuf()** here:

[Making fgets issue longer read() calls on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3612363)

I’m still having a really hard time getting this to work – here’s the bit of my code that I’m struggling with:

```
int main(void) 
{ 
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 7168

char input_string[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

printf( "Input: " );

setvbuf( stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

fgets( input_string, MAX_STRING_SIZE-1, stdin );

printf( "\n" );
printf( "%s", input_string );
}
```

Has anyone had success increasing this input buffer?

My environment: Ubuntu 10.10 with the build-essential package

Thanks!

Comment: What if you use `fread()` instead of `fgets()`.

Comment: I just tried fread() but it seems to have the same issue.  I'm only able to paste 4096 bytes into the terminal window when prompted for input.

Comment: So the application requires that the data is "pasted" into the terminal? `fread()` and even `fgets()` should be OK if file redirect `<` operation is used. Ofcourse you could read the data in character by character. It should work for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you're using `_IONBF`, which means *no* buffering. Using `_IOFBF` instead would probably be a good start (that's *full* buffering). To increase the buffer size, you'll also want to specify that large buffer size as the fourth parameter, something like:

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOFBF, 16384);
```

This allocates the buffer space dynamically. Depending on the situation, you might want to pass it the buffer instead:

```
char mybuffer[32768];

setvbuf(stdin, mybuffer, _IOFBF, sizeof(mybuffer));
```

Comment: Hmm - I've changed the line to read:  "setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOFBF, 16384);" but it still seems to have a hard limit at 4,096.  This small bit of code is prompting for an input and I'm simply trying to paste a string of 4,261 characters into the terminal window.  The string is still cut off right at the 4,096 mark.

Comment: @Nate: At a guess, that's unrelated. It sounds like you're running into a buffer limitation built into the terminal window's line editor. `setvbuf` only changes a buffer that's built into the standard library. When you read data from your terminal, it'll be copied from the terminal's 4096 byte buffer into the one you specify -- but changing the one in the library won't affect the on built into the terminal. You *may* be able to change the terminal's buffer size, but if so it'll probably be with something like an `ioctl`.

Comment: @Jerry: I know I'm hitting some buffer but I'd agree that I don't know which one (:   When I'm in my Ubuntu terminal window at a normal command prompt I can paste the full 4261 bytes, only when I execute my C program and it asks for input does it restrict me to the 4096.

Comment: @Nate: The main point is that it's almost certainly *not* the one controlled by `setvbuf`, so nothing you can do with `setvbuf` is likely to help.

Comment: @Jerry: Well thanks for helping confirm that.  I'm trying to modify some existing code.  I'll have to rework a little more of this code to read from a file.

Comment: I just found a simple work around that helped me bypass my 4096 input limitation.  I doubt it’s the best solution but satisfies my needs.
Rather than prompting the user for input I’m able to pass the 4261 byte stream as a program parameter from the terminal before the C program launches.  First I changed the main function line to this `main(int argc, char *argv[])` then the following grabs my really long parameter `strncpy(input_string, argv[1], sizeof(input_string)-1);`.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I have experimented with buffer sizes in the past, and found little benefit in increasing it. If you're using any higher-level input functions like `fgets` (or worse, `fgetc` or `fscanf`), enough time will be spent searching for delimiters or in function call or parsing overhead that the number of `read` syscalls really doesn't matter that much, as long as the buffer is at least 1kb or so. If on the other hand you're reading large blocks at a time (via `fread`), the implementation should be smart enough to skip buffering entirely and read directly into the buffer provided by the caller. As such, I generally consider `setvbuf` as useless, albeit probably harmless, micro-optimization.