# How to increase the STDIN BUFFERSIZE

Tags: linux, debian, buffer

I'm using Linux Debian 6.0.6, I'm facing a problem in STDIN Buffer. 
To get input from STDIN, I'm not able to enter more then 4095 characters in STDIN, 
is there any way to increase the STDIN buffer size.

Comment: How is this a problem? Why are you letting data sit in the buffer in the first place?

Comment: my $val=<STDIN>;
print $val;
print length($val);

I have tried with bash read, C scanf, etc,
all the programs waiting for user input , I tried to give 5000 characters like 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12345677ABC' without space. after
 entering the 4095th character the shell is not getting input otherthen enter. my shell is "/bin/bash"

Answer (score 1):

The buffer size is like kernel's page size.
If you want to do your job with C, check man setbuf(3).
Also, here's already answered question. [Using setvbuf() with STDIN stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876373/using-setvbuf-with-stdin-stream)

If you want to do it with shell, just give a try stdbuf(1).